# Hadoop Understanding :: Fundamentals

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

Just a few questions on Hadoop. Please share your experiences.

1) If I have to store a 1TB file on hadoop cluster, assuming the replication factor to be 3,does it mean that I have uploaded a file of 3TB?

2)How is the client machine configured to the Hadoop cluster?Please provide specifics of the files that need to be modified.

3)How is Hadoop cluster different from a traditional network distributed system?
We know that traditional distributed systems also have a master-slave architecture.But there is this communication amongst the slaves while performing any task.
Question is if similar communication mechanism exists amongst the Hadoop DataNodes?

4)If there is no communication amongst Hadoop DataNodes how is the Sort and Shuffle phase making data transfers on DataNodes once the map task is completed?

5)This is with respect to Cloudera QuickStart VM 5.5, when I do "sudo jps" in terminal window,no processes related to JobTracker and TaskTracker are running yet
my MR jobs are getting submitted and outputs are written to HDFS.
Is this because of a running process name "JobHistoryServer" that shows up when I type "sudo jps" command?

6)Assuming a scenario when the JobTracker submits an MR job to a DataNode(DN1) which is already running so many tasks and cannot accept anymore,the NameNode with its Rack Awareness knowledge will delegate this MR job to  other nodes in same rack.Let say the new node is DN2
Now,question is whether DN2 will copy the block's data from DN1 and runs MR job or is it just going to run the MR job on behalf of DN1 as the block of data is visible across the Hadoop distributed cluster?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Best,
Sri

Comment: I understand you are new to StackOverflow, but please limit your posts to one question each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are the answers to your questions :

1. You upload only 1 TB file. The file gets splitted into chunks(blocks) of 128   MB(default in yarn) each. Now each block is replicated in three different nodes. So ultimatley you upload 1 TB and the 3 times replication is taken care by hadoop.
2. You can install hadoop on a single node as well as on a cluster of machines. Please go through the following blogs which gives the step wise step and detailed picture of how you can configure it.

   http://teamvj.blogspot.in/2014/02/installing-hadoop-single-node-cluster.html

   http://teamvj.blogspot.in/
3. Hadoop Namenode is the master node which has the information about all the datanodes aperating under it. Datanodes send periodic signals called heartbeat to the namenode signalling that they are alive and ready to take up tasks. Namenode has information about which datanode contains which block. So when a job is submitted the processing goes to the correct node which has the data on which processing has to be done. If the datanode fails, the other datanode having the same block(because of replication) is given the task. Hadoop Cluster is the same old distributed computing but what makes it special is they way it operates like fault tolerant, speculative exectuion etc.
4. Datanodes always communicate to each other for transfer of blocks from one datanode to other. Suppose one datanode is down so the replication of the data sotred in it also comes down. At that moment transfer of blocks from one datanode to other is required.
5. The data will go to the DN which has the copy of the block already. That is the real idea behind storing replicas. IF one datanode having the block is unavailable , the request will go to one of the other two datanode which have the block assuming the replication factor is still the default value that is 3.

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad it helped you Sri

Comment: Just a query after thinking about it, regarding the network traffic..If hadoop takes care of the block replication..the name node eventually has to replicate the remaining 2TB onto datanodes after receiving 1TB. Since datanodes are connected through common dedicated n/w,doesn't this replication account for network traffic??